# Acessing data members of more than one parent classes in python

Tags: python

I want to access variables from two parent classes to a child class, in other words, how to access data members of parent classes in case of multiple inheritance ?

For e.g.,

```
Class A(object):
    # class A variables
    def abc(self):
        # method variables
Class B(A):
    # class B variables
    def xyz(self):
       # xyz method variables
class C(B, A):
    ## I want to access the variables from Class A and B here in Class C. Both      class variables as well as method variables.
```

Comment: The same way you would in single inheritance; have you actually *tried anything*? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Note that *"method variables"* are local to the method, so aren't accessible outside whether or not you're in a class.

Comment: How about... `class C(B, A): var = A.var`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inside C

```
A.abc(self)
B.xyz(self)
```

to reach to variables you can either use

```
A.varA
B.varB
```

But I believe that the proper way to do it is by creating "get" methods inside Class A and Class B.

Comment: Neither part of your answer is a Pythonic way to approach this; you're ignoring `self` and `super` and getters and setters are pointless when you have properties.